# deamon authentication on powerapps admin REST API

Tags: azure-active-directory, powerapps

In scope of a compliance monitoring app for our powerapps usage, we created a C# console app which crawls powerapps.

- environments
- applications
- permissions

(similar REST call than powershell commands `Get-AdminPowerAppEnvironment` `Get-AdminPowerApp` provided by [Microsoft.PowerApps.Administration cmdlets](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Microsoft.PowerApps.Administration.PowerShell))

proof of concept was done by stealing the Bearer header from fiddler when connected with my admin AAD account. POC is now validated, time to make it clean. And as often with AAD auth flow (for me), it's more complex than expected (*sum up of hours of try & fails*).

I find really little internet reference on how to authenticated & crawl (this part is ok) this API.

I tried different auth workflow and lib

- MSAL
- ADAL
- fiddler on top of powershell command (but in powershell I'm not using a service principal)

and either I can't spot the correct scope or my service principal has no permission on the resource.

1. I have an `App registration` called `AAA powerapps` with ... quite a lot of permission (try & fails)
   [image]
2. Created a client secret
   [image]
3. just in case, put into Power Apps administrator
   [image]

```cs
            string authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/[tenant-guid]/";

            var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .CreateWithApplicationOptions(new ConfidentialClientApplicationOptions {  ClientId = "[client-id]", ClientSecret = "[shhuuuu]" })
            .WithAuthority(authority).Build();

            // tried with https://management.azure.com/.default / https://api.bap.microsoft.com/.default / https://service.powerapps.com./default
            var token = app.AcquireTokenForClient(new[] { "https://management.azure.com/.default" }).ExecuteAsync().Result; 

            //var client = new RestClient("https://api.bap.microsoft.com/providers/Microsoft.BusinessAppPlatform/scopes/admin/environments?api-version=2016-11-01");
            var client = new RestClient("https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.BusinessAppPlatform/scopes/admin/environments?api-version=2016-11-01");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token.AccessToken);
            IRestResponse response = client2.Execute(request);
```

I get a token, but I don't think it's on the correct scope/resource unfortunately.
Depending on the scope, I either get

- **Forbidden**

```json
{"error":
{"code":"Forbidden","message":"The service principal with id '[service principal guid (not client id)' 
for application <null> does not have permission to access the path 'https://api.bap.microsoft.com:11779/providers/Microsoft.BusinessAppPlatform/scopes/admin/environments?api-version=2016-11-01' in tenant [tenant-guid]."}}
```

or

- **Unauthorized**

```json
{"error":{"code":"AuthenticationFailed","message":"Authentication failed."}}
```

Comment: May I know what is the "PowerApps Service" resource in your [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wk91C.png)? I can't find it from my AAD. If it's exactly the resource you are trying to access, you should add **Application Permission** rather than **Delegated Permission** because service principal uses Application Permission.

Comment: adding the powerapps service was more a desperate move test. According to the REST endpoint called "https://api.bap.microsoft.com/providers/Microsoft.BusinessAppPlatform/xxx" I would more think the actual API is Azure Service Management. "Application permission" rather delegated make sense, but it's grayed out. I tried to find article for appRoles configuration in the manisfest but I have the understanding it's only for custom API, which isn't my situation.

Comment: I think it's not Azure Service Management. Azure Service Management is used to call Azure resources. Usually we can assign a RBAC role to the service principal to give it application permission. But PowerApps don't appear under Azure resources. Based on this [package](https://168.61.186.235/packages/Microsoft.PowerApps.PowerShell/1.0.18/Content/Microsoft.PowerApps.RestClientModule.psm1), I see that `"api.bap.microsoft.com" = "https://service.powerapps.com/"`. Looks like `https://service.powerapps.com` is the resource endpoint. But I still can't find where we can assign permission for it.

Comment: From this [link](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Microsoft.PowerApps.Administration.PowerShell/2.0.100) I notice that most cmds has `cds`. `cds` is common data service. If the data is from common data service, you could look into [this post](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Apps-Pro-Dev-ISV/Service-Principal-setup/m-p/544173/highlight/true#M2278) which may be helpful. It is using an application user to access PowerApps.

Comment: looked with interest in the link you provided, so got the feeling switching from "regular" AAD way (app registration, etc) to "classic" non interactive admin account linked with ADAL/identitymodel (XRM). Following up your links i found this interesting repo : https://github.com/microsoft/PowerApps-Samples/blob/master/cds/webapi/C%23/GlobalDiscovery/GlobalDiscovery/Program.cs

will check if possible to "steal" the correct token from there . unfortunately I will have to wait because our account per default requires MFA/2 auth and I need to poke our admin.

Comment: Any luck on this?

Comment: got "luck" yesterday, but with using an AAD user rather app registration and some MFA exceptions, still sure/hoping there are other better ways... I willl elaborate in one answer later today.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't succeed with `client id` & `client secret` but managed to call `api.bap.microsoft.com/../Microsoft.BusinessAppPlatform` with AAD user.

eg `https://api.bap.microsoft.com/providers/Microsoft.BusinessAppPlatform/scopes/admin/environments?api-version=2016-11-01`

re-used same method as [Microsoft.PowerApps.Administration cmdlets](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Microsoft.PowerApps.Administration.PowerShell)

1. AAD account with AAD `Power platform administrator` [role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/use-service-admin-role-manage-tenant#assign-a-service-admin-role-to-a-user)
2. If Multi Factor Access enabled for admin, create exception rule
3. use ADAL nuget `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory`
4. dotnet

```cs
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/common");

var credentials = new UserPasswordCredential("admin_powerapps@domain.net", "password");

// "1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2" = client ID for Azure PowerShell.
// available for any online version
var token = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", "1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2", credentials).Result;

// any REST call
Header "Authorization" : "Bearer " + token.AccessToken
Endpoint : https://api.bap.microsoft.com/providers/Microsoft.BusinessAppPlatform/scopes/admin/environments?api-version=2016-11-01
```

results
[image]

The benefit from this method is that it can crawl "all" environments seamlessly (not sure the approach with creating a user on each was working).
Another approach I spotted was using [Powerapps connector for admin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/powerappsforadmins/) but it involved extra configuration on each environments and required a license.

Not fully sure this method would be supported long term (eg xx.windows.net). Open minded for any other suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. What solved it with me is to register the app with tenant admin rights on the power platform admin using this command `New-PowerAppManagementApp`. Please, find MSFT article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/powershell-create-service-principal#registering-an-admin-management-application).

After your client application is registered in Azure AD, it also needs to be registered with Microsoft Power Platform. Today, there's no way to do this via the Power Platform admin center; it must be done programmatically via Power Platform API or PowerShell for Power Platform administrators. A service principal cannot register itself—by design, the application must be registered by an administrator username and password context. This ensures that the application is created knowingly by someone who is an administrator for the tenant.

```
$appId = "CLIENT_ID_FROM_AZURE_APP"
# Login interactively with a tenant administrator for Power Platform
Add-PowerAppsAccount -Endpoint prod -TenantID $tenantId
# Register a new application, this gives the SPN / client application same permissions as a tenant admin
New-PowerAppManagementApp -ApplicationId $appId
```